# onResume() in BaseActivity is getting called in all the activities which extends BaseActivity

Tags: android

In my application, bluetooth device scanning code is written in `onResume()` method in `BaseActivity`.

I extended some activities with `BaseActivity` so, if I switch to any activities, bluetooth scanning is being done.

Is there any way to write `onResume()` in `BaseActivity` works only once? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to move that code in the `onCreate` method?

Comment: Sounds like BaseActivity is not the right place to do yiur BLE scan. Why don't you use a Service ?

Comment: Yes, I tried in onCreate, the same is happening

Comment: Are you overriding the `onResume()` method in the other activities and call `super()`?

Comment: try removing super.onResume(); in on resume() method in all activities.

Comment: It works the way it is supposed to. You should move your logic out of onResume, or call it by a condition.

Comment: bt scanning write in single instance then write in onResume() if (bt.isScanned()) continue.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how inheritance works. But you can overwrite the onResume in your subclas with an empty method.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
     // no super class is called

}
```

But i think there is something wrong with your program design.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static Boolean IsResumecalled = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!IsResumecalled) {
        IsResumecalled= true;
        //write your code here
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your active Bluetooth connection should not reside in the `BaseActivity`. It rather should bind itself on his `onCreate()` via `bindService` to the `BluetoothService` - so it does not matter if one `Activity` destroys itself and the next one is getting started, because the `Service` is not Acitivity-dependent.

Look here for the general android developer guide on `BluetoothService`
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

And and how to use `Services` namely the `bounded Service`
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

There are also google code examples which you can use as a guideline.

It's a bad idea to block the `onResume()` call since it's a important part of the lifecycle for example if you minimize and maximize the app.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onResume` in your child activities but do not call `super.onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
     // super.onResume(); // do not call this line in your child activities
}
```